# How to create a randomly connected graph in OMNeT++?

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to create a graph with randomly connected nodes.
Nodes should be connected randomly and if a node is already connected to another node, it shouldn't be connected to the same node again using different `inout` port.

[In the docs](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:random-graph-example) there is this example to create a random graph:

```cpp
module RandomGraph {
    parameters:
        int count;
        double connectedness; // 0.0<x<1.0
    submodules:
        node[count]: Node {
            gates:
                in[count];
                out[count];
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        for i=0..count-1, for j=0..count-1 {
            node[i].out[j] --> node[j].in[i]
                if i!=j && uniform(0,1)<connectedness;
        }
}
```

But this method might connect the same two nodes multiple times using different ports which is not what I want.

[image: connected nodes]

As you can see from the above screenshot `node1` is connected to `node6` through two different ports.

I do not want this behavior because in my code I am sending a message to all the out ports using a for loop which then sends the same message twice to the same node.

I could try eliminating multiple connections to the same node in the `initialize()` function I guess, I just thought of it while I am creating this post. I've not tried it yet but I will and will share the result.
I would like to hear your solutions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you used should be corrected in the manual. The inner for-loop has to start from the current value of the index in outer loop. Moreover, the operator `++` should be used for gates, because according to OMNeT++ Manual:

> The gatename++ notation causes the first unconnected gate index to be used.

Thanks to `++` there is no need to maintain the index of the gate to connect.
The last change: both input and output gates should be connected when the condition is met.
The corrected code of your NED may looks like:

```
module RandomGraph
{
    parameters:
        int count;
        double connectedness; // 0.0<x<1.0
    submodules:
        node[count]: Node {
            gates:
                in[count];
                out[count];
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
        for i=0..count-1, for j=i..count-1, if i!=j && uniform(0,1)<connectedness {
            node[i].out++ --> node[j].in++;
            node[i].in++ <-- node[j].out++;
        }
}
```

**EDIT**
Simplified code concerning @Rudi suggestions:

```
module RandomGraph
{
    parameters:
        int count;
        double connectedness; // 0.0<x<1.0
    submodules:
        node[count]: Node {
            gates:
                in[];  // removed the size of gate
                out[];
        }
    connections allowunconnected:
       for i=0..count-2, for j=i+1..count-1, if uniform(0,1)<connectedness {
            node[i].out++ --> node[j].in++;
            node[i].in++ <-- node[j].out++;
        }
}
```

Comment: Oh, wow. At first, I thought this would not work but then after trying it out and writing down a few steps, it is clear to see that it works. Thank you!

Comment: Just checked... The example in the manual is correct because that is using unidirectional ports where you indeed have to run through each node pair two times (i.e. for each direction). The error is because OP has used bidirectional gates without correcting the loops. (The code listing and the screenshot are inconsistent!) For bidirectional gates, this code is right.

Comment: A few recommendations: a) You may need to remove the gate size definitions in `Node` if you use `++` on gates. b) you can simplify the code even further: `for i=0..count-2, for j=i+1..count-1, if uniform(0,1)<connectedness {
            node[i].port++ <--> node[j].port++; }`

You can get rid of the i!=j test :)

Comment: BTW, there is an example for this (bidirectional random graph in samples/neddemo): https://github.com/omnetpp/omnetpp/blob/master/samples/neddemo/RandomGraph.ned

Comment: @Rudi, yes, I was using bidirectional gates in my code, didn't realize it would matter. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: :) Actually, I made the same error in the above example in `neddemo`. Just corrected in the master branch of omnetpp.